# Pydantic 1.8.2 doesn't recognise the list

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I was using pydantic 1.7.2 to deserialize the data on one fastAPI, now I download the latest version of pydantic 1.8.3, and the new version is having problems to deserialize List in python.

Anyhelp with this?

My class is :

```
class Person(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = None
    last_name: str = None


class YearClass(BaseModel):
    yearClass: str = None
    alumnno: List[Person] = None
```

The rest api:

```
@router.put("/class/update")  
async def insert(yearClass: List[YearClass] = None):
    print("update class")
```

I am calling the endpoint

curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:8000/class/update -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '[{"yearClass":"Y10","ingredients":[{"first_name":"Ana","last_name":"Smith"},{"first_name":"Paula","last_name":"Smith"}]}]'

But the rest api is return 422 -  unprocessable entity

I much appreciate any help
Thank you so much

Comment: I think you have an issue in the data. You specify `ingredients` instead of `alumno`!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, yes you're right, it was a silly mistake. Thanks